# How do I add Main Menu to xib

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xib

I deleted main menu from my xib file. How can I recreate it without coping it from 
another freshly created xib?

I can't seem find how to tell IB that menu that I add from object library is actually main application menu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. You used to be able to simply connect the `mainMenu` outlet to your menu, but as of Xcode 4, there is no `mainMenu` outlet and there is no replacement way to create a Main Menu in an existing nib.

You must create a new MainMenu nib using the New File command and either copy the Main Menu object from that nib or just replace the old nib with the new.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't appear you can set a menu as main menu inside the IB however if you open the xib in a text editor (or in xcode click right click on the xib file name in file explorer then Open As->Source Code).  You can add attribute to the menu tag:

```
systemMenu="main"
```

this will yield:

```
<menu title="Foo" systemMenu="main" id="some-id">
```

After you save the file IB will reread it as main menu.